# Internationalization string testing

Tags: testing, internationalization

Some people using look-alike Unicode symbols to replace English characters to test the internationalization, e.g. "Test" is replaced as "Ťėşŧ". Is there a wellknown name for this language/culture? Are there utils, keyboard layouts, translation tools for this "language"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of this technique is **Pseudolocalization**, see the Wikipedia article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization

Windows Vista comes with three [Pseudo-Locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319106(v=VS.85).aspx) for testing. The "[Using Pseudo-Locales for Localization Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374118(VS.85).aspx)" MSDN article may be a good place to start.

Beyond this, any tool (beyond what you would use for regular localization, such as a translator) would depend on what platform you are developing for (and so how your data is stored).

As for keyboard layouts - any will do. But don't forget about [IME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)s.